# What is the genus of the Riemann Surface $ w = z \,(\,1 + 0.5\, z^4\,) $?

Tags: complex-analysis, homology-cohomology, riemann-surfaces

I drew a spirograph curve $X = \{ (\cos \theta + 0.5 \cos 5 \theta, \sin \theta + 0.5 \sin 5 \theta): \theta \in [0,2\pi]  \}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 $ I would like to know what is the genus?  Is it birational to a circle?  I think not because the inverse map involves solving a quintic.  Do we need to complexify and consider the Riemann surface $X(\mathbb{C})$?  I know the sphere $w^2 + z^2 - = 0$ has genus $g=0$.

This curve is the image of the unit circle under the map: $z \mapsto w= z \,(1 +  0.5\, z^4)$ and I'm asking if the image curve is birational to a circle.

[image]

---

**Fixes**

The comments say the answer might be yes...!  Could you point me to a proof of that?  This might not be elementary, the obvious map $z \mapsto f(z)$ doesn't work... so is there another map taking $X(\mathbb{Q}) \leftrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ ?

There might be an error in my question... I have drawn the image of the curve $\{ |z| = 1\} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ by the curve $z \mapsto f(z)$ in the $w$-plane, and I'm asking for the genus of that image.  Is that image curve birational to a circle? There are rational points $(x,y) = (\pm 1.5,0), (0, \pm 1.5)$ and we could find the intersection $\ell \cap X$ of the curve and a line with rational slope and I guess we could construct a map?

Comment: Any curve of the form $w=f(z)$ with $f$ a polynomial is a rational curve.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown could you point me to a proof of that?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown if the genus is zero, then what could be the map.  we know all genus zero curves are [birationally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birational_geometry#Birational_maps) equivalent.  I guess this is the case for [stereograhic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection).

Comment: Is there a mistake in your equation ? As Lord Shark said, any curve of the form $w=f(z)$ has genus 0, because any such curve is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ by $z\mapsto (z,f(z))$, whose inverse is $(z,w)\mapsto z$. Such curves are graphs of function, but your picture does not look like a graph.

Comment: I think OP is using a shorthand for $x=\cos t +\tfrac{1}{2}\cos 5t$, $y=\sin t +\tfrac{1}{2}\sin 5t$. This curve is rational since it's parametrized by the circle and the circle is rational.

Comment: @KBDave right.  My question now is that if $cos t, \sin t \in \mathbb{Q}$ we're not guaranteed that $x=\cos t +\tfrac{1}{2}\cos 5t \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $y=\cos t +\tfrac{1}{2}\cos 5t \in \mathbb{Q}$.  So there has to be *another* map giving the Birational equivalence.

Comment: So the answer follow from Lüroth theorem : you have a rational map $\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow X$, so $X$ is necessarily of genus 0.

Comment: We actually are guaranteed that: for any natural number $k$, $\cos k t$ and $\sin kt$ can be given as polynomials in $\cos t$ and $\sin t$.

Comment: @KBDave sorry. Backwards:  $x=\cos t +\tfrac{1}{2}\cos 5t \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $y=\cos t +\tfrac{1}{2}\cos 5t \in \mathbb{Q}$ does not imply $\cos t, \sin t \in \mathbb{Q}$.  There could be others...

Comment: But it's *bi*rational. Starting with a rational parametrization of $X$, you can express the parameter as a rational function of the $x$ and $y$ components of $X$ and then write $\sin$ and $\cos$ in terms of that parameter. If
$$R(x, y) = \frac
 {2 x (16 (x^4 + x^2 (2 y^2 + 1) + y^4) - 48 y^2 - 9)}
 {80 x^4 + 32 x^2 (y^2 - 1) - 48 y^4 - 9},$$
then
$$\cos t = R \left(
 \cos t + \frac 1 2 \cos 5 t, \sin t + \frac 1 2 \sin 5 t \right),$$
with the exception of a finite number of points where the denominator is zero.